# HTML drag n drop sound

Tags: jquery, html, audio, drag-and-drop

I am currently trying to do the html drag and drop table with different Continents. The person will have the ability to drag the right continent in to the div where it suppose to be. I have done all the div tags and drag n drop functions, but what i also want to add is sound. I have two sounds right.mp3 and wrong.mp3. I want so they could play when the person gets the right continent in to right place and when its the wrong one (right one as right.mp3 and when wrong one is palced the wrong.mp3). I have try many different ways of doing the sounds but unfortunately i could not get it to work right. If there is some one who knows how to do it i would be really great-full if you showed me how exactly it looks in code. Below is the code i have done so far. Thank you.

P.S I am sorry for my English as it is not my first language and sorry for any inconvenience it caused.Thank you.

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #div1
            {float:left; width:500px; height:250px;border:1px solid;
                position: absolute;
                background-image:url('Winkel_triple_projection_SW.jpg');
                background-size:500px 255px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: -10;
            }
            #div2
            {
             width:80px; height:108px; margin:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: white;
                z-index: -1;
             position: absolute;
                margin-top: 100px;
                margin-left: 120px;
            }

            #americainside
            {
                width:100px; height:150px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
            #div3
            {
                width:95px; height:100px; margin:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: white;
                z-index: -2;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 90px;
            }
            #northmurica
            {

                width:100px; height:130px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
            #div4
            {
                width:95px; height:100px; margin:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: white;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 80px;
                margin-left: 220px;
            }
            #Africa
            {
                width:100px; height:129px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
            #div5
            {
                width:200px; height:80px; margin:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: white;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-left: 232px;
            }
            #Europe
            {
                width:210px; height:120px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
            #div6
            {
                width:71px; height:58px; margin:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: white;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 140px;
                margin-left: 390px;
            }
            #Australia
            {
                width:100px; height:100px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
            #div7
            {
                width:300px; height:40px; margin:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: white;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 210px;
                margin-left: 90px;
            }
            #Southpole
            {
                width:355px; height:70px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
            #right
            {   width:360px;
                border:5px solid #aaaaaa;
                float:right;
                margin-right: 30%;
            }
    </style>
        <script>
            function allowDrop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev)
            {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
    <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
    <div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
    <div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>


    <div id="right">
        <div id="americainside" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            South America
            <img src="South america.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"

                 id="drag2" width="80px" height="108px"></div>

        <div id="northmurica" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            North America
            <img src="North america.png" alt="North America" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"

                 id="drag1" width="95px" height="100px"></div>

        <div id="Africa" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Africa
            <img src="Africa.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"

                 id="drag3" width="95px" height="100px"></div>
    <div id="Europe" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Europe
            <img src="Europe.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"

                 id="drag4" width="200px" height="80px"></div>

        <div id="Australia" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Australia
            <img src="Australia.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"

                 id="drag5" width="71px" height="58px"></div>

        <div id="Southpole" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Southpole
            <img src="south pole.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"

                 id="drag6" width="350px" height="40px"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I do know there are other things i can use for this but I want to do it with HTML. Still i would not mind if you suggest other possible options. I obviously don`t ask for any one to do the whole job, but if you could at least show me the one example it would be really great. Thank you.

Edit : I also am looking for the button which will clear the div tags after they are moved somewhere.

Edit 2 : I have added the play function as Alexander T suggested , but i am sure that doing something wrong here.
Code :

```
        <script>
            function allowDrop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev)
            {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                ev.playSound;
            }
        var path = 'cat.mp3'
            function playSound(path) {
                var sound = new Audio(path);
                sound.play();
            }

        </script>
```

This wont work. I guess i am not calling the function right. If any one could show me how to do this right. Thank you.

Edit: This is how it looks now, but still not working. Not sure what i am doing wrong here tho.

```
        <script>
            function allowDrop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev)
            {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
            }
            function drop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                playSound("catSound");
            }
            function playSound(path) {
                var sound = new Audio(path);
                sound.play();
            }



        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTML5 audio API.

```
function playSound(path) {
    var sound = new Audio(path); 
    sound.play();
}
```

where 'path' is a string with path to your sound, e.g. `'/audio/rightSound.mp3'`

there are a bundle of methods anв properties for `Audio` object in JS. Find it here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp
And here is very good article about using Audio in HTML5 http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Comment: I see. But how do i make it play when the items is being dropped in to window?

Comment: When you say path should be the string with path u mean something like this? 
var path = '/audio/rightSound.mp3'

and then the path

Comment: `function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.playSound;
}`

should look like:

    `function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      playSound("/audio/rightSound.mp3");
    }`

Comment: Added that. Does not seem to be working. Edited the code if you could take a look at it and tell what is wrong with it, would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: not `playSound("catSound");` but `playSound("catSound.mp3");` if you have catSound.mp3 file placed in the same directory as your index.html is.